# std::unordered_map access violation on emplace

Tags: c++, access-violation, unordered-map

I have two `typedefs`:

```
typedef std::function<void(SDL_Event)> EventCallback;
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, EventCallback> EventCallbackContainer;
```

And in my `EventManager` class I add it just as this:

```
EventCallbackContainer m_eventCallbackContainer;
```

I know of no way to initialize a map and as I understood it I shouldn't have too.

In the `EventManager` I have a `addCallback` template function which I call, it then emplaces it into the `std::unordered_map` but as I do I get a access violation, looking at the VS watch it seems like the `std::unordered_map` is `NULL`.

The addCallback function:

```
template<class Class>
inline void EventManager::addEventCallback(std::string gameStateID, void(Class::* func)(SDL_Event), Class* instance)
{
    EventCallback callback = std::bind(func, instance, std::placeholders::_1);
    m_eventCallbackContainer.emplace(gameStateID, callback);
}
```

VS watch:
[image]

I am not sure why this is the case or how I could fix it.

Projects whole codebase if you need more context(don't feel obligated too look though, it is NOT intended as a codereview): [Github with codebase](https://github.com/Dequilla/TheGame/tree/master/Game%20With%20Engine)

Comment: Is `this` null?

Comment: Sigh, yes seems so, let me take an extra look then.

Comment: MY BAD, found the problem, thank you kind anon. I was initializing another class before my eventManager  that calls addCallback meaning it calls it before EventManager even exists, again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being stupid. Apparently I was initializing a class that calls addCallback before a EventManager was created.

NOTE TO SELF: Remember to check if `this` is NULL.